# A tag [logging] deveria ser um sinônimo para [log]?

Tags: debate, tags-sinônimas

Existem duas tags com propósitos muito parecidos. Veja a wiki de [logging](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logging) (3 perguntas):

> Logging é uma expressão utilizada para descrever o processo de
>   registro de eventos relevantes num sistema computacional.

E de [log](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log) (73 perguntas):

> É o registo de dados do computador ou o processo de gravação de
>   eventos de um programa de computador, geralmente com um certo alcance,
>   de modo a fornecer um rastro de controle, que pode ser utilizado para
>   compreender a atividade do sistema e para o diagnóstico de problemas.

Aqui no Brasil, nesse contexto, o termo "log" é muito mais utilizado que "logging"

[image]

Concorda que [logging](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logging) deveria ser sinônimo de [log](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log)?

Comment: Concordo com o inverso, log deveria ser sinônimo de logging. Pra mostrar que não é uma ideia estranha, já é assim no SOen. Mas isso porque não me lembro no momento uma palavra em português que possa expressar "logging". A propósito teria que fazer um merge dessas wikis.

Comment: @EMBarbosa penso que logging é um termo em inglês, portanto no SOen faz sentido, mas não necessariamente fará sentido para nós, claro que usamos tags como [tag:debug], mas na área de TI é comum usarmos, agora penso eu que [tag:logging] é mais dificil que escrever [tag:log] ... e log é mais comum (creio eu, não posso afirmar). Então creio que para os nossos usuários é mais fácil escrever log. Mas é apenas sugestão.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento como eu disse: *Mas isso porque não me lembro no momento uma palavra em português que possa expressar "logging"*. Se tivesse uma palavra que expressa a ação de criar um log em português que fosse de uso geral acho que ela deveria ser a principal.

Comment: @EMBarbosa penso que quase tudo é uma ação, sendo o AP que queira criar a ação ou o AP tentando entender pq de uma ação não ocorrer, ou uma ação existente dentro de um sistema/tecnologia. Creio que se isso justificar algo deveria então justificar o uso de coisas `debugging`. Do meu ponto de vista apenas penso que o ideal é procurar facilitar para o usuário final (`User-eXperience`), pois penso que o termo `logging` para que usa frequentemente ou nativamente seja algo natural e por isso é mais fácil que `log`, mas para uma comunidade em português eu creio que seja incomum. Mas é opinião apenas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendi seu ponto de vista. Não sou contra colocar logging como sinônimo de log. Acho que no momento o mais importante é colocá-los como sinônimos. Na minha opinião, não faz tanta diferença assim quem é a tag principal.

Answer (score 4):

É um debate, então cada um tem sua opinião, e na minha acho que sim, a [logging](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logging) deveria ser sinônimo da tag [log](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log).

Alguns motivos:

- *Logging* é bem estrangeiro. Se eu fosse procurar na internet por armazenamento de eventos que ocorreram no sistema (automaticamente me lembra *log* (de erros, acesso, modificações)) eu encontraria *log*. Não acredita? [Veja então](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Armazenamento+de+eventos+de+sistema&oq=Armazenamento+de+eventos+de+sistema&aqs=chrome..69i57.8367j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), dos 10 resultados que apareceram, nenhum mostra o termo *logging*.
- Queremos um Stack Overflow em Português, então acho legal termos os termos ingleses (sempre que possível) traduzidos para o português, com os sinônimos estrangeiros.
- *Log* cobre perfeitamente a [definição](http://www.aulete.com.br/Log) de *logging*:

  > Arquivo de computador que guarda automaticamente qualquer operação efetuada
- Mais rápido e fácil de escrever também. Imagine se rapidamente, eu escrever ***loging***, então não iria encontrar a tag desejada, eu teria que procurar por ela ... resumindo mais trabalho. Talvez pode se dizer, que basta criar um sinônimo <strike>errado</strike> que nem acontece com [htaccess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htaccess), mas é desnecessário esse *workaround*.

Comment: Compartilho da opinião, como pode notar no meu comentário na pergunta :)

Comment: Acho que o último ponto não faz muita diferença. Se as tags forem sinônimas e você escrever *log* já funciona. Não precisa escrever tudo.